# Error while running bash script that moves files

Tags: bash, scripts

I am new to bash script and want to create bash script that moves some days old files between source and destination as per days defined in script.

When I run this script I get error

find: paths must precede expression: mv Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Your Source Directory"
read soure

echo "Enter Your Destination Directory"
read destination 

echo "Enter Days"
read days




   find $soure -mtime +$days  mv $soure $destination {} \;

  echo "Files $days old moved from $soure to $destination"
```

What's missing or wrong ???? please help me to create this script.

Comment: As an fyi, bash scripting usually falls under StackOverflow...  since that's where coders hang out...

Comment: `mv` is a command , not an argument .The way you have written `mv` is taken as an argument of `find`.You either need it to be passed through -exec argument or pipe (`|`) the results from find to `mv`

Comment: Mevin's comment is correct.  You should also quote your "$variables" before spaces in paths cause you trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you've already come across them already, but the two best places to begin with learning bash scripting are the [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html) and the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). If you haven't seen these two resources yet, I would highly recommend bookmarking them if you're looking to do further bash scripting.

Removed portion regarding flow control due to edit in question. The find command needs `-exec` before the command or else it won't know that `mv` is actually a command you're attempting to execute on the files. Also, the `{}` in the find is used to refer to the results of the find command, thus you won't need `$source` as part of the find. The find command would probably look more like:

```
find $source -mtime +$days -exec mv {} $destination \;
```

If the find results will include files/directories with spaces in them, then you may need to loop through the results (which will bring the do/done back into the mix) so that you can include the results of the find in a variable that can then be enclosed in quotes. That will give a structure similar to the following:

```
for result in $(find $soure -mtime +$days)
do
    mv "${result}" $destination
done
```

If you're still having problems, I'd suggest including a copy of your terminal window from running the script. Also, try running just the find command by itself without the `-exec mv...` portions and replacing the variables with what you'd normally fill in for them during the script execution. That way you can get an idea as to what the find command is matching so you can be certain that it's matching the files you want it to before making any changes to the location of your files.

Comment: Thank You.... Are pdf versions are available of above guides ???

Comment: There may be PDF versions, but I've never checked, always preferring to read them directly online.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have a for statement before the do loop, in order for it to work. Look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/), for more information on Bash loops.

Comment: I don't need loop I want just simple script

Comment: In that case, it should work if you remove the `do` & `done` statements.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!